# Pandas Calculating minimum timedelta by group

Tags: pandas, timedelta

My input data frame as below:
Input Dataframe:

```
Input1 = pd.DataFrame({'LOT': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'A3', 3: 'A4', 4: 'A5'},
 'OPERATION': {0: 100.0, 1: 100.0, 2: 100.0, 3: 100.0, 4: 100.0},
 'TXN_DATE': {0: '12/6/2016',
  1: '12/5/2016',
  2: '11/30/2016',
  3: '11/27/2016',
  4: '11/22/2016'}})

Input2 = pd.DataFrame({'LOT': {0: 'B1', 1: 'B2', 2: 'B3', 3: 'B4', 4: 'B5', 5: 'B6'},
 'OPERATION': {0: 500, 1: 500, 2: 500, 3: 500, 4: 500, 5: 500},
 'TXN_DATE': {0: '12/7/2016',
  1: '12/3/2016',
  2: '11/17/2016',
  3: '11/22/2016',
  4: '12/4/2016',
  5: '12/3/2016'}})
```

I am interesting to calculate companion lot from Input2 to lot in Input1 table based on minimum TXN_DATES delta between them (time delta suppose to be minimal):

Final DataFrame:

```
Expected_out =  pd.DataFrame({'COMPANION_LOT': {0: 'B5', 1: 'B5', 2: 'B4', 3: 'B4', 4: 'B4'},
 'COMPANION_LOT TXN_DATE': {0: '12/4/2016',
  1: '12/4/2016',
  2: '11/22/2016',
  3: '11/22/2016',
  4: '11/22/2016'},
 'LOT': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'A3', 3: 'A4', 4: 'A5'},
 'OPERATION': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100},
 'TXN_DATE': {0: '12/6/2016',
  1: '12/5/2016',
  2: '11/30/2016',
  3: '11/27/2016',
  4: '11/22/2016'}})`
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: My purpose to find companion lot that ran operation 500 to lot that ran operation 100 based on time delta between these lots, i.e for each lot that ran operation 500 i need lot that ran operation 100 with minimal timedelta between them. Hope it helps.

Comment: The best is if add some manual formula what you use for count output. For me is unclear why in output are 2 columns `TXN_DATE`, groups are  by column `OPERATION`?

Comment: One column in output is "TXN_DATE" and second column in output is "COMPANION_LOT_TXN_DATE"

Comment: sorry, I see it bad.

Comment: But there groups are in rows with `OPERATION == 100` two - one rows with index `0,1` and second rows with index `2,3,4` , but for `OPERATION==500` there are no change?

Comment: no change. lot from operation 500 is companion to itself

Comment: Is any way not to split table by operations?

Comment: I still dont understand, so hard to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129975/discussion-between-jezrael-and-felix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mainly [`pandas.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) and then add new column by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
Input1.TXN_DATE = pd.to_datetime(Input1.TXN_DATE)
Input2.TXN_DATE = pd.to_datetime(Input2.TXN_DATE)

Input1 = Input1.sort_values('TXN_DATE')
Input2 = Input2.sort_values('TXN_DATE')
df = pd.merge_asof(Input1, Input2, on='TXN_DATE', suffixes=('','_COMPANION')) \
       .sort_values('LOT') \
       .drop('OPERATION_COMPANION', axis=1)
df['LOT_TXN_DATE'] = df.LOT_COMPANION.map(Input2.set_index('LOT')['TXN_DATE'])
print (df)
  LOT  OPERATION   TXN_DATE LOT_COMPANION LOT_TXN_DATE
4  A1      100.0 2016-12-06            B5   2016-12-04
3  A2      100.0 2016-12-05            B5   2016-12-04
2  A3      100.0 2016-11-30            B4   2016-11-22
1  A4      100.0 2016-11-27            B4   2016-11-22
0  A5      100.0 2016-11-22            B4   2016-11-22
```